# Definition of "Recently Read"- and "Recently Added"-Categories in Mendeley

Tags: mendeley

My team is currently working on an integration of the Mendeley reference platform into our Web-App. We want to display the references of a logged in user in a sidebar.

To provide a familiar look and feel, we structure the data received from API calls like the original Mendeley library page ("All Documents", "Favorites", "My Publication", folders, groups, and subfolders), but we found no way to categorize a document/reference as "Recently Read" and/or "Recently Added".

- How are those two defined?
- Is there a way to request only recently read or recently added documents through the API or to calculate which of all documents fall into that category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no public API endpoint to provide the list of "Recently Read" documents.

As for "Recently Added" - you can obtain these with the publicly available API. Take a look at https://api.mendeley.com/apidocs/docs#!/documents/getDocuments. You can retrieve a list of documents ordered by their creation time.

Example GET URL for "Recently Added"

```
https://api.mendeley.com/documents?view=client&sort=created&order=desc&limit=50
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any limitation to how many references are kept in recently added?

Comment: Hey @daniel-bücherl. You should be able to access all documents owned by the current user using the api.mendeley.com/documents endpoint. However, if the number of documents exceeds the limit pagination will occur. You can read more about it here: http://dev.mendeley.com/reference/topics/pagination.html

Comment: Maybe the question was a little bit imprecise formulated. I know how the pagination works. The question is: do you internally keep only a certain amount of documents in the category "recently added" (e.g. 200) or is it just a sort? If after uploading the 201st documents the first uploaded falls out of there, I would like to mirror that behavior.

Comment: Hello. The API itself, as we discussed, does not have limitations since it is a simple sort.

Mendeley only provides documentation and support about the publicly available APIs. "Recently Added" is not an API concept which means that clients are free to implement it however they like.

This means, if possible, you shouldn't assume a particular implementation since it is not guaranteed to always stay the same.

Comment: Bottom line is I can't really provide you with a concrete answer since we can't commit to always support the same definition of "Recently Added".

Comment: Thanks for your help. That was what I needed. If you could also have a look at my new question, it would be awesome: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895586/requesting-csl-or-bibtex-from-api